# While downloading file from FTP Server, getting an error message from Apple

Tags: objective-c, ftp, download

I am using FTPManager code to download a file from FTP server. In my app, i am getting a request from TCP server to download a file and then play. 
Sometimes FTP manager code downloads the files and then my app plays it well, but if i get a similar request again ,then  sometimes i am getting an error message in console

**request (0x15598b20) other than the current request(0x0) signalled it was complete on connection 0x156aec50**

After this message it doesn't play the downloaded file as well.

if i try to capture in the code, where i am getting this message, i didn't get any idea. I don't think that message is sent by code.

Code to download the file is

```
 server = [FMServer serverWithDestination:@"ftpserver username:@"****" password:@"*****"];


        FTPManager *man = [[FTPManager alloc] init];
        NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

     success =    [man downloadFile:filename toDirectory:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path objectAtIndex:0]] fromServer:server];


    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(PlayAudio) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I am always getting success as true even with this message.